# automating zsh shell scripts within OS X

Tags: macos, zsh

Is there a way to automate a task (zsh shell script) using some type of scheduler. If so, how?

For example, if I am running a zsh shell script within my system named zshprogram1.zsh within the directory /Users/myname/zshtest and I want to run it at 1:35 PM HST daily, how would I go about doing that? Also, I'm assuming it would only work if my laptop is on. Will it work if it's on but in sleep mode?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [crontab](http://crontab.org/) or [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).

For example, with crontab you would run `crontab -e` from Terminal and paste the following line into the editor that comes up

```
35 13 * * * /Users/myname/zshtest/zshprogram1.zsh
```

to have zshprogram1.zsh run at 1:35 PM every day. Launchctl is a bit more complicated to configure, but Apple recommends it over crontab for the future, so it might be worthwhile to check out.

Comment: Okay. I tried using vi to create the crontab using the string above, with the replaced name holders for myname. When I did so and then entered crontab -l to see if it had been implemented, I get a message that says there is no crontab for user.